# Web Scraping using python and generating a price on a site

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

So basically I am doing a school project that involves web scraping. I understand how to use python and incorporate web scraping, but how do I put that scraped data onto a website. If it helps I am making  a website that pulls prices from other sites, and displays it on mine. (Like Trivago) I can't find much online so any help would be great.

Comment: You want some way to communicate the data you have scrapped to the backend of some other website. The easiest way to do this is to put the data you scrap in a database.

Comment: Do you have any experience with web-dev? I can recommend some ideas based on your experience.

Comment: im fairly confident in HTML and CSS, but python is a kind of let down. If it helps im trying to create a tool that takes prices from sites such as steam, eb games, xbox live etc. then have a site that contains a catalogue of games, and compares the cheapest option

Comment: from my knowledge, its possible to use python to scrape the info, then back it onto a data base, then upload that data base to the html site, use the python code in the html, but i really have no clue. Web scraping is a very new term to me

Comment: If you know HTML and CSS, web scraping should be easy enough. JavaScript could be something you want to watch out for tho. A lot of websites nowadays are rendered almost entirely on the client-side using JavaScript, so if the webscraper can't handle JS, you might be screwed.

Comment: If you're squeaky on python, and don't know web-dev (besides HTML/CSS), I recommend you take this course https://www.edx.org/course/cs50s-introduction-computer-science-harvardx-cs50x It is a big investment of time and effort, but you'll be able to churn out better code, and will sort of know what you should do when working on programming projects in general. The course is free, and you'll learn C, python, MVC, web-dev, and about databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run an application server either on your pc or on some cloud provider's cloud (AWS, IBM, etc.). If you run it on your PC you will have to deal with SSL certs, DNS leasing, etc, opening up your router, etc. Flask is a simple python web server.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/

If you want to keep it simple, find some html templates that you can pre-populate server side with your data and then serve to client.

If you don't have experience with javascript or HTTP, those are necessary dependencies and where I would start. HTTP is the glue between a browser and your web server, and javascript is necessary to make just about anything happen in a web browser.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp